# Laravel Sendmail SMTP Gmail

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail, laravel-8

I built my Laravel project in XAMPP on my localhost, and when I deployed the project to my shared host, the mail does not send. It was working fine in my localhost, and I tried every solution on StackOverflow and Google. There is nothing that works for me: my email is with Gmail, so I used their SMTP info in my .env file.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:5yMVTQwQlBQF0G0h4IM7Cqemh0hKis4+VC5S9vdhfgc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://example.com

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=example
DB_PASSWORD=example

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=example@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Hey Farouk - are there any errors in the Laravel log? How are you sending your emails? Could you provide an example of the script you are using?

Comment: Some hosting providers do not allow relaying the mail through third party servers on shared hosting or require the relay services to be enabled on request. Check with your hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

First you try this

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
```

And when not working this then you go gamil and login your gmail and `My account > Sign In And Security > Sign In to google`, enable two step verification, then you can  app password, and you can use that app password in .env file.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=app password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

After that clear cache may be this work

Answer (score 0):

Login in into your gmail create app and set password to it.

```
MAIL_Driver: smtp
MAIL_HOST: smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT: 465
MAIL_USERNAME: abc@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD: app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION: ssl
```